# How to capture/intercept network api calls (Request and Response) with webdriverio framework?

Tags: automation, interceptor, webdriver-io, wdio

I am trying to capture all the api's called on clicking submit action using **wdio-intercept-service ** npm library with method browser.getRequests({includePending: true }) in WebDriverIo framework.
Total 3 api's gets called on clicking submit button: beacon, getPNR, fulfilPNR.
Right now when I click on Submit, it returns only 1 beacon api which gets called on every UI action. The other 2 apis are not captured.

Can't we capture other user defined api's with this service?

I am using Wdio-intercept-service version : 4.3.1.